# Externally loaded SWF from application directory not loading twice

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loader

I have an external SWF that I'm planning on using to load movieclips with content that would need to be able to change without altering the source file.

I get it to load perfectly fine and everything runs great, then I unload it, set the values to null just to be safe and the app still operates fine without errors, but when I try to load it a second time, my traces show me that it's loading 100%, but the final onComplete function just seems to not be triggering unless I click the load button again, but then it loads another copy of the swf.

Anyone experience anything similar or know what's going on?

Edit:  Here's an example of the code:

```
var swfFileName:String = "path/to/file.swf";
            var swfFilePath:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(swfFileName); 
            var inFileStream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
            inFileStream.open(swfFilePath, FileMode.READ); 
            var swfBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            inFileStream.readBytes(swfBytes);
            inFileStream.close(); 

            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
            loaderContext.allowCodeImport = true;
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoaded);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, imageLoading);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, loadError);
            loader.loadBytes(swfBytes, loaderContext);
```

And this is the removing code:

```
function remover(event:Event = null):void {
                    loader.unloadAndStop();
                    loader = null;
                    swfFileName = null;
                    swfBytes = null;
                    loaderContext = null;
                    trace("removed");
                }
```

There is some content added in the swfLoaded function and removed the the remover function, but I have removed those to try to narrow down the cause in this example.  From traces I've done the Percentage trace in the Progress event is the last thing that fires at 100 before nothing else happens during a second load of the function.  The first time I try to run it, it runs fine and displays all content with perfect functionality.

Comment: Share your code.  Our telepathic-fu is still weak.  ;)

Comment: How are you `unloading` the SWF?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem finally.  It turns out that this line:

new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);

Was causing it to become out of context for removal for some reason I don't fully understand.  I fixed it by allowing the default settings to run:

new LoaderContext();

The only downside being I have to do a bit more work with loading and working with the library objects inside of the external swf, but now it works again.